# addVectorLayer('filename','layername','ogr') loads layer and names it "filename layername featuretype"

Tags: pyqgis

I have a PyQGIS script that loads shapefile to the canvas with this line:
`iface.addVectorLayer('pathto/file.shp','layername',"ogr")`

It was working fine and was always loading layer named 'layername', but now it is loading layer and naming it `'layername file Polygon'`, with exact same script. Do you know why? Same thing happens in both QGIS 2.18 and 3.2.

[image]

Comment: My QGIS 3.2.0 returns it without the feature type, so I see "name ShapeTest". The .name() method on the layer returns that as well, so its not just the way it is being displayed in the legend...

Comment: Seems the be a feature of the OGR provider, since adding a memory layer this way doesn't have that effect.

Comment: Creaeting a layer with `L = QgsVectorLayer(fl, "name","ogr")` doesn't add odd things to the name, and then adding it to the project with `QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(l)` (QGIS 3 I think) doesn't add it on either... Odd..

Comment: Thanks for checking! at least there's a workaround in QGIS 3 then.